# Magento 2 How create front controller with a specific path?

Tags: controllers, redirect, redirect-url, router, routes

I want create controller for specific path, but i can't know how i can do this.

My controller must work with path like: site.com/**usa/some-review/dynamicParam**

My path for controller: site.com/**some-review/index/index**

How i can create controller for **usa/some-review/dynamicParam** or forward redirect from **usa/some-review/dynamicParam** to **some-review/index/index**?

Thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create custom router (matcher) for route to your action controller

**1. Define your custom router**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="acme_stackexchange" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Acme\StackExchange\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2. Create Routed and implement your match logic**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Controller/Router.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Controller;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward as ActionForward;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected ActionFactory         $actionFactory;
    protected EventManagerInterface $eventManager;
    protected StoreManagerInterface $storeManager;
    protected ResponseInterface     $response;

    public function __construct(
        ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        EventManagerInterface $eventManager,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ResponseInterface $response
    ) {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->eventManager  = $eventManager;
        $this->storeManager  = $storeManager;
        $this->response      = $response;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function match(RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $requestPath = $request->getPathInfo();
        if (!str_contains($requestPath, '/some-review/')) {
            return null;
        }

        // optional create event
        $condition = new DataObject(['request' => $request, 'custom' => 'custom_value']);
        $this->eventManager->dispatch(
            'acme_controller_router_match_before',
            ['router' => $this, 'condition' => $condition]
        );

        // example to verify in store if needed
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();

        // parse request and set your action if applicable
        $request->setModuleName('acme')
            ->setControllerName('result')
            ->setActionName('review');

        // you can set dynamic variables to request like
        $request->setParam('param_name', 'param_value');

        return $this->actionFactory->create(ActionForward::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much) I did the router in the same way, but I didn’t go into my class with the help of debugging, maybe I made a mistake somewhere and your code helped me

Answer (score -1):

You can create the Frontend Controller with the specific path by :

Create this file:

app/code///etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="VendorName_ModuleName" frontName="path">
            <module name="VendorName_ModuleName" />
        </route>
     </router>
</config>
```

For Controller we will create this file :

app/code///Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     public function execute()
     {
         echo 'Hello World';
         exit();
     }
}
```

The File Structure of the Magento is below :

```
├── app
│   └── code 
│        └── Magefan // назва розробника - VendorName
│            └── Faq // назва модуля - ModuleName
│                ├── etc
│                │   ├──module.xml
│                │   └──frontend
│                │      └── routes.xm
│                │
│                ├── registration.php
│                └── Controller
│                    └── Index
│                        └── Index.php
│
```

Then run these commands :

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:f

php bin/magento s:di:c
```